# How does next() work in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently read a blog in [Nodejitsu](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-middlewares) and I am wondering how this piece of code works.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('../lib/node-http-proxy');


module.exports = function (logging) {
  // Code here is run when the middleware is initially loaded.
  var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./requests.log');

  return function (request, response, next) {
    // Code here is run on each request.
    if (logging) {
      logFile.write(JSON.stringify(request.headers, true, 2));
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

And the explanation given for this piece of code is:

> This middleware is for very simple logging - it will write the headers of each request to a log file.

the above module exported can be used as,

```
httpProxy.createServer(
  require('./example-middleware')(true),
  8000, 'localhost'
).listen(9000)
```

How is the code in the above method with `next()` invoked in every request? The usage is pretty simple: require the above module and it gets invoked every time.

Comment: As Node is single threaded, I suppose "next" just sets a timeout to call the same function again when a new request comes in.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris not quite. `next()` tells whoever called this function that it's done and the next function in the middleware stack should be called.

Comment: @chasles, gratzi. Still sounds like it sets a timeout to call the same function. The "same" function might just be a little higher in the call stack then previously suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll simplify the actual process but the gist of it:

When a request comes in, node passes the request and response object to the first middleware in the middleware stack. If that middleware sends a response or closes the connection in any way, then subsequent middleware are not called. Otherwise, that middleware has to tell node it's finished doing it's job to keep on moving through the middleware stack, so you call next() within your middleware to tell it to continue processing middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is a pretty common thing. What this module contains is a single function, specified by this line, where we set module.exports to a function, `module.exports = function (logging) {`. The function returned by the module (and therefore returned by `require()`) returns another function, which is the middleware for the HTTP proxy (this middleware allows you to transforms the request). This middleware function gets called for every HTTP request made to the server. Quickredfox's answer provides a fairly good explanation of middlewares.

So the `require('./example-middleware')(true)` actually calls the function assigned to `module.exports`, but does not call the function inside that, which is returned immediately and passed as a middleware into the `httpProxy.createServer` function. This is a good way to set up some options for your middleware using closures. If you have any more questions, feel free to comment. :D