# Who provides the next() function in Express middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm confused about how `next()` works in Node.js and Express middleware.

There have been some other questions about middleware works, [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103465/how-does-next-work-in-node-js), but I'm looking for a different answer.

**The main question bugging me** is, who is providing the `next()` function?

For example, in my standard generated `express` app, I'm given this code:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

But who calls this function and what is the nature of the `next()` that it provides? How do I know what the `next()` will look like? I have no idea what next() does.

Comment: It is simply a callback. When you execute `next`, you are telling express that you are done here and it should continue on with the next middleware , or handle any passed in errors.

Comment: *"who is providing the next() function"* Expressjs is. It's there so that you can indicate when that middleware is done executing.

Comment: @KevinB Why then don't you pass a callback with next to the next piece of middleware, like `next(req, res, myNextFunc);`?

Comment: Why would you need to? each middleware shouldn't care what middleware will be called next or what the result of calling said next middleware will be. Express will already give the next middleware the appropriate req res and next arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An Express application is essentially a series of middleware calls.
>
> Middleware is a function with access to the request object (req), the
>   response object (res), and the next middleware in line in the
>   request-response cycle of an Express application, commonly denoted by
>   a variable named next.

As written above, Expressjs provides the next callback function. Next is just a way of calling the next middleware in the flow.

For many examples see Express's [Using middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html)